# Multiple Analytics accounts in one Maui app

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, maui, maui-blazor

I have a Maui Blazor hybrid app where users open the app and are presented with different clients to select. Once they select a client they can login and the api for that client is used to access everything.

I need a way to track analytics separately for each client.

I have set up multiple firebase accounts set up to the same app, but I have not clue how I would switch after the app is running or if it's even possible.

Comment: You can check this document about [Add authentication to your .NET MAUI app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/mobile-apps/azure-mobile-apps/quickstarts/maui/authentication).